# Como colocar autocomplete no Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text

Eu uso o Sublime Text 3 para programar só que o *autocomplete* não me está a funcionar. Já instalei o *plugin* Sublime Intelcode mas mesmo assim não funciona. Não aparece as sugestões quando vou a escrever o código. Como resolver?

Comment: Não encontrei isso

Comment: aparece os plugins que tenho instalados, mas antes de mais qual o melhor plugin para autocomplete ?

Comment: [Aqui](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/auto-complete) há alguns, isso vai depender da sua necessidade, a versão que usas, a linguagem. Com *Ctrl* + *Space* não funciona?

Comment: funciona mas eu queria que aparece a lista conforme ia escrevendo

Comment: eu estou neste ficheiro aparece isto {
 "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Monokai (SL).tmTheme",
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ]
}

Comment: coloquei isso mas mesmo assim não funciona eu agora removi todos os plugins e vou instalar só o de autocomplete qual e o na tua opinião o melhor para todas as linguas ou seja principalmente css php e jquery

Comment: Olhe para [PHP Completions](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHP%20Completions%20Kit).

Comment: eu acho isto estranho eu instalo o autocomplete para css se eu criar um css no arquivo php o autocomplete funciona bem num ficheiro .css nao funciona

Comment: Pode ser uma característica, talvez para *css* você tenha que ter outro *plugin*.

Comment: Bem já esta a funcionar como queria mesmo obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Se for possível poste uma resposta de como você conseguiu e aceite ela.

Comment: Sim eu vou reformular uma resposta detalhada com as alterações que fiz com certeza irá ajudar outras pessoas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bem vou publicar aqui como resposta a solução de como resolvi o meu problema, pelo que vi na internet existe muita gente a procurar por esse problema.

Primeiro verifiquei no menu `Preferences/Settings-User` se o `"auto_complete": true,` estava activado caso não esteja tem que colocar conforme `"auto_complete": true,`

Depois e instalar os plugins necessarios para fazer o efeito de `autocomplete` conforme as vossa necessidade vou deixar aqui os plugins que utilizei e que funcionam na perfeição.

**CSS Extended Completions**

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Extended%20Completions

**Emmet**

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet

**Sublime​Linter**

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter

O que vou colocar a seguir e `Opcional` e uma sugestão minha mas para quem passa muitas horas a programar penso que seja um bom tema para cansar menos a vista.

**Spacegray theme**

http://kkga.github.io/spacegray/