# Autocompletar lista ul>li*n no Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Vendo vários tutoriais na internet onde usam o Sublime Text 3 para editar códigos HTML, digitam `ul>li{item}*4` e depois <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> o Sublime completa o código com:

```
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Tentei usar alguns plugins e mesmo assim o atalho não funciona.

Instalei os plugins que estão nessa pergunta: [Como colocar autocomplete no Sublime Text 3?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52513)

Uso o **Sublime Text 3 Build 3126** no Windows 10.

Comment: Isso é atalho gerado pelo Emmet, mas por padrão ele só fica disponível em arquivos HTML. Você salvou o arquivo antes de tentar inserir o atalho (ou alterou a sintaxe com `Ctrl+Shift+P + HTML`)?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Salvei sim e conferi que a sintaxe selecionada é na barra de status é HTML.

Comment: Reiniciou o editor após a instalação? Tentou pressionar `Tab` após digitar o atalho?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Sim, reiniciei, fiz isso em outro computador com o Windows 7 também e não funciona.

Comment: Tenta reinstalar o package então. Eu uso essa mesma versão e aqui funciona normalmente. Confirme também se ele está instalado em `Ctrl+Shift+P + List Packages`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, desisntalei o plugin `Ctrl+Shift+P` e depois `Remove Package` selecionei o Emmet, reiniciei, instalei denovo, esperei baixar o PyV8, reinciei novamente e nada... será que estou fazendo algo errado? `ul>li{teste}*5` depois `Ctrl+Espaço` é isso mesmo?

Comment: Aqui eu uso o `Tab` no lugar de `Ctrl+Space`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse tipo de atalho é definido no pacote [Emmet](https://emmet.io).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para utilizar, basta digitar a estrutura desejada e pressionar <kbd>Tab</kbd>. É importante salientar que o atalho só funcionará, por padrão, em arquivos HTML, então é necessário certificar-se que a sintaxe está correta no canto inferior direito do editor.

Comment: E, caso seja necessário alterar a sintaxe do documento atual para HTML, basta fazer o seguinte:

Mac OS: Cmd + Shift + P --> Set Syntax: HTML
Windows / Linux: Ctrl + Shift + P --> Set Syntax: HTML